# Calling Async method inside Foreach loop JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, closures

I'm trying to make a Async call to Google Maps for address inside a foreach loop.

This is the function:

```
//Function to get address from geographic coordinates
        function getAddress(item) {
            var address = 'Not fetched';
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.Latitude), parseFloat(item.Longitude));
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        address = results[0].formatted_address;
                });
                return address;
        }
```

This is the loop:

```
 recreateMarkers: function (self, data) {
                        data.vehicleInfo.forEach(function (item) {
                            self.Location= getAddress(item);
                        });
                    }
```

Structure of Data:
1. VehicleId
2. Latitude
3. Longitude
4. Location

Now the problem is it gives me same or undefined location for all vehicles.

Would be glad if someone can assist.

Comment: This wouldn't even work without the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem of asynchronous ,

`return address` is executed before google fetched address is assigned by `address = results[0].formatted_address;` so your function should be something like this

```
 function getAddress(item) {
            var address = 'Not fetched';
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.Latitude), parseFloat(item.Longitude));
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        address = results[0].formatted_address;
                        return address; //<= this statement should be here
                });
           // Note return address; should not be here
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. Still it says undefined.